# At what kind of places will my ship scanned for contraband?

Tags: rebel-galaxy-outlaw

In the game, there are Station (in space and Ports on planets) and Outposts.

Every now and then the police will scan you for contraband.

Are there specific places where police will scan my contraband more frequently, like, Outposts will be 100% but Ports are 0%?

Or are those scans random?